# Counting a character in a string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have been asked to count the number of times the character(given by the user) appears in the string (given by the user) without using string class .count methodology nor dictionary (hasn't come to that point yet) in python. Is there any way to find the count of how many times the character gets repeated?

```
user_string = "Hello! What a fine day it is today."    
user_character = "e"   
count = 0   
for a in user_string:   
     if user_string == user_character:         
     count += 1    
print(count)
```

I know the above code is wrong since it compares the full string with an individual character. So it would be helpful if someone can correct it and provide a program.

Comment: `if a == user_character:` ? The loop is iterating over the whole input string one character at a time - and that character is placed in the variable `a` ...

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice it though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious change to fix your program is the if-condition:

```
count = 0   
for a in user_string:   
    if a == user_character:         
        count += 1    
print(count)
```

Beyond that, you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to make it more concise:

```
count = sum(a == user_character for a in user_string)
```